# Wordpress Error : "Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in" How to fix?

Tags: wordpress

**Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array in**

C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress-4.3.1\wp-includes\query.php on line 3716

i dont know what is this i am searching from internet but not find the solution

Comment: Turn off all your plugins and then activate one by one..

Comment: no its not the issue